# Change WPF Tabcontrol Header Background based on ItemSource value

Tags: c#, wpf

i try to change the background of my TabControl based on a bool which is declared in the ItemSource object. The ItemSource of the TabControl is an list of UC_Instance. I dont know where to start here respectively I dont know, how to tell the TabControl to look on each item which is binded separately.

If the getter (HasFailedConnections) in UC_Instance.cs returns true, it should color the background of the TabControl header red.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

**TabControl.XAML**

```
                <TabControl x:Name="TabItems" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="16,0,0,0" Style="{x:Null}" Height="270" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AddionalInstanceList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DealerNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              ContentSource="Header"
                                              Margin="10,2"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </TabControl>
```

**UC_Instance Class**

```
using Devology.Lib.Internal;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Atbas.NET.UserControls
{
    public partial class UC_Instance : UserControl
    {
        public bool HasFailedConnections
        {
            get
            {
                if(ServerAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.Failed || UpdaterAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.Failed || PortAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.Failed || DatabaseAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.Failed || 
                ServerAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.None || UpdaterAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.None || PortAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.None || DatabaseAvailable == Enums.ConnectionTestResult.None)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty DatabaseCouldNotBeFoundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DatabaseCouldNotBeFound", typeof(string), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public string DatabaseCouldNotBeFound
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DatabaseCouldNotBeFoundProperty);
            set => SetValue(DatabaseCouldNotBeFoundProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty DatabaseNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DatabaseName", typeof(string), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public string DatabaseName
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DatabaseNameProperty);
            set => SetValue(DatabaseNameProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ServerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Server", typeof(string), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public string Server
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(ServerProperty);
            set => SetValue(ServerProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty DatabasePortProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DatabasePort", typeof(int), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public int DatabasePort
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(DatabasePortProperty);
            set => SetValue(DatabasePortProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty DealerNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DealerNumber", typeof(string), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public string DealerNumber
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(DealerNumberProperty);
            set => SetValue(DealerNumberProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty UpdaterIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UpdaterId", typeof(int), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public int UpdaterId
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(UpdaterIdProperty);
            set => SetValue(UpdaterIdProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty DataFromNetFolderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataFromNetFolder", typeof(bool), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public bool DataFromNetFolder
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(DataFromNetFolderProperty);
            set => SetValue(DataFromNetFolderProperty, value);
        }


        public static DependencyProperty ServerTestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ServerAvailable", typeof(Enums.ConnectionTestResult), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public Enums.ConnectionTestResult ServerAvailable
        {
            get => (Enums.ConnectionTestResult)GetValue(ServerTestProperty);
            set => SetValue(ServerTestProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty PortTestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PortAvailable", typeof(Enums.ConnectionTestResult), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public Enums.ConnectionTestResult PortAvailable
        {
            get => (Enums.ConnectionTestResult)GetValue(PortTestProperty);
            set => SetValue(PortTestProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty DatabaseTestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DatabaseAvailable", typeof(Enums.ConnectionTestResult), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public Enums.ConnectionTestResult DatabaseAvailable
        {
            get => (Enums.ConnectionTestResult)GetValue(DatabaseTestProperty);
            set => SetValue(DatabaseTestProperty, value);
        }

        public static DependencyProperty UpdaterTestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UpdaterAvailable", typeof(Enums.ConnectionTestResult), typeof(UC_Instance));

        public Enums.ConnectionTestResult UpdaterAvailable
        {
            get => (Enums.ConnectionTestResult)GetValue(UpdaterTestProperty);
            set => SetValue(UpdaterTestProperty, value);
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = new Regex("[^0-9]+").IsMatch(e.Text);
        }

        private void TextBoxPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(String)))
            {
                String text = (String)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String));
                if (new Regex("[^0-9]+").IsMatch(text))
                {
                    e.CancelCommand();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }


        public UC_Instance()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DatabaseCouldNotBeFound = "Die Datenbank wird beim Test automatisch anhand der hinterlegten Händler-Nr. ermittelt.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make a converter like boolToColor and bind the background property to HasFailedConnections + the converter to transform the bool into a color [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
 public class CodeToColorConverter : IValueConverter

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But how do I tell the xaml code that it has to send the index[x] to this converter or does he make this for each element individually?

Comment: try it but it should work Background="{Binding HasFailedConnections , Converter=....because the datacontext is the item in the source